# A functional equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, derived-functors

Let $u$ be a mapping from $(0,1)$ to its self. I m interested in a class of functions $u$ for which the following equation admits a solution $f: (0,1) \to R$ which is derivable in $(0,1)$ :

$$
f\circ u= f +1
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you take for example

$u\;:\;x\mapsto x$

then, there is no solution.

Comment: Yes. Here I m interseted in which conditions on $u$ so that the equation has a solution.